# Orika mapping nested sublist

Tags: java, mapping, orika

Consider the below example.

Group.java(GroupDTO.java also has the same properties)

```
import java.util.List;

public class Group {
    public Group(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    private List<Person> persons;

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }
}
```

Person.java(PersonDTO.java also has the same properties)

```
import java.util.List;

public class Person {

    public Person(){}
    public Person(List<Name> names, Integer age) {
        this.names = names;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private List<Name> names;
    private Integer age;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Name> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(List<Name> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }
}
```

Name.java(NameDTO.java also has the same properties)

```
public class Name {
    public Name(String first, String last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    private String first;
    private String last;

    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }
}
```

And when I run the below class I get the following exception.

```
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade;
import ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory;
import ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.ClassMapBuilder;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Mapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Name> names = new LinkedList<Name>();
        names.add(new Name("foo", "bar"));
        names.add(new Name("lorem", "ipsum"));
        List<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person(names, 30));
        persons.add(new Person(names, 40));
        Group g1 = new Group(persons);

        MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
        ClassMapBuilder classMapBuilder = mapperFactory.classMap(Group.class, GroupDTO.class);
        classMapBuilder.field("persons{age}", "persons{age}");
        classMapBuilder.field("persons{names{first}}", "persons{names{first}}");
        classMapBuilder.field("persons{names{last}}", "persons{names{last}}");
        classMapBuilder.byDefault().register();

        MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
        GroupDTO groupDTO = mapper.map(g1, GroupDTO.class);

        for(Person p:groupDTO.getPersons()){
            System.out.println(p.getAge());
            for(Name n:p.getNames()){
                System.out.println(n.getFirst());
                System.out.println(n.getFirst());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:104)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.buildMapper(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1480)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.build(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1295)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.getMapperFacade(DefaultMapperFactory.java:883)
    at Mapper.main(Mapper.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.specification.MultiOccurrenceToMultiOccurrence.registerClassMaps(MultiOccurrenceToMultiOccurrence.java:397)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.specification.MultiOccurrenceToMultiOccurrence.generateMappingCode(MultiOccurrenceToMultiOccurrence.java:72)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.SourceCodeContext.mapAggregateFields(SourceCodeContext.java:721)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.addMapMethod(MapperGenerator.java:182)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:70)
    ... 4 more
```

Sorry about the long post. Am trying map fields from inside List<> which is again inside another List<>. What would be the best approach or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If the field names on both sides are equal, you don't have to register the field mappings, Orika will handle that by itself. This code will do the mapping correctly:

```
    MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
    ClassMapBuilder classMapBuilder = mapperFactory.classMap(Group.class, GroupDTO.class);
    classMapBuilder.byDefault().register();

    MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    GroupDTO groupDTO = mapper.map(g1, GroupDTO.class);
```

Also, probably just a typo, but the `getPersons()` from `GroupDTO` should return `PersonDTO`, same for `getNames()` and `NameDTO`:

```
   for(PersonDTO p:groupDTO.getPersons()){
        System.out.println(p.getAge());
        for(NameDTO n:p.getNames()){
            System.out.println(n.getFirst());
            System.out.println(n.getLast());
        }
    }
```